# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to implement a web service using Spring 4 and Jackson.
When I deploy an application I receive this following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]
Offending resource: class path resource [namaservlet-servlet.xml]
```

This is my namaservlet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper">
          <bean class="utils.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
        </property>
      </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
  </mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stracktrace suggests that you are missing `spring-webmvc` jar in your classpath. Add it and it should work fine